# What keeps turning my monitor on?

Tags: display, laptop-display, events

I've got a laptop that's suffered some chassis damage that makes it very cumbersome to open/close the laptop. Normally, the metal ends of the LCD hold onto the chassis, but in this case the magnesium alloy plastic that holds the screws is broken. The laptop is out of warranty and it'd be a bit expensive for me at the moment to send it off to HP for repair. There's a wire that runs up from the motherboard to the LCD. That wire is rubbed up against by the metal part every time I open or close the lid on the laptop. So to avoid further damage to my laptop (at least until I can get it fixed), I've made a simple program to shut the monitor off on command. It basically just uses the following:

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2);
```

It works just fine and it allows me to keep my laptop open indefinitely. The only problem is that some program keeps waking my screen up. There's almost nothing open, and I can't come up with anything immediately obvious.

I was just wondering how you guys would go about figuring out what's turning on my display? Can you recommend any software and maybe some information on what events/specifics I should be looking out for?

Comment: So you still use the monitor, not an external one, right?

Comment: Maybe it's some USB device that wakes it up.

Comment: Yes I still use the monitor. With an external monitor I'd be able to just push the power button to turn it off.

Comment: Why not just set the screen saver timeout to turn the display off after a few minutes?

Comment: Also, look at Control Panel -> Admin Tools -> Task Scheduler.  Very often there is some useless task that's scheduled to run every few minutes.

Comment: I didn't find much in task scheduler but you got me to check the event log. I created a custom view for everything in the past hour. Every time the monitor turns on it's because of Service Control Manager, which notifies me which services have started or stopped. It's a mix of essentials and non-essentials and it doesn't make a difference. It doesn't look like there's an elegant workaround thus far so I've updated my program to SendMessage every 30 seconds until I press Esc. Bit nasty but it'll do for now.